# WooCommerce changing order of product informations

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress and plugin WooCommerce I need to change order of things on product page to: title with price in one row, then product description, and finally in last row number of pieces and add to cart button. I was trying to rewrite almost everything in WooCommerce templates but I can't do it. (I got woocommerce folder in my template folder.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, to override any of the woocommerce template files, you need to follow appropriate directory structure within your theme folder.

In your case, you would want to override template files that are responsible for the display of single product page i.e. woocommerce/templates/single-product/

Now to override the template file in your theme, follow below directory structure

```
your-theme-folder/woocommerce/single-product/<file.php>
```

If you are using child-theme (recommended) then,

```
your-child-theme-folder/woocommerce/single-product/<file.php>
```

Also there is a way to override woocommerce template file from plugin. For more information, read this article - http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/override-woocommerce-templates-plugin/